# Can this cython code be optimized?

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython

I am using cython for the first time to get some speed for a function. The function takes a square matrix `A` floating point numbers and outputs a single floating point number.  The function it is computing is the [permanent of a matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_the_permanent)

[image]

When A is 30 by 30 my code takes about 60 seconds currently on my PC.

In the code below I have implemented the Balasubramanian-Bax/Franklin-Glynn formula for the permanent from the wiki page.  I have called the matrix M.

One sophisticated part of the code is the array f which is used to hold the index of the next position to flip in the array d. The array d holds values that are +-1.  The manipulation of f and j in the loop is just a clever way to update a Gray code quickly.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython


DTYPE_int = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_int_t
DTYPE_float = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_float_t

@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function
def permfunc(np.ndarray [DTYPE_float_t, ndim =2, mode='c'] M):
    cdef int n = M.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_float_t, ndim =1, mode='c' ] d = np.ones(n, dtype=DTYPE_float)
    cdef int j =  0
    cdef int s = 1
    cdef np.ndarray [DTYPE_int_t, ndim =1, mode='c'] f = np.arange(n, dtype=DTYPE_int)
    cdef np.ndarray [DTYPE_float_t, ndim =1, mode='c'] v = M.sum(axis=0)
    cdef DTYPE_float_t p = 1
    cdef int i
    cdef DTYPE_float_t prod
    for i in range(n):
        p *= v[i]
    while (j < n-1):
        for i in range(n):
            v[i] -= 2*d[j]*M[j, i]
        d[j] = -d[j]
        s = -s
        prod = 1
        for i in range(n):
            prod *= v[i]
        p += s*prod
        f[0] = 0
        f[j] = f[j+1]
        f[j+1] = j+1
        j = f[0]
    return p/2**(n-1)
```

I have used all the simple optimizations I found in the cython tutorial.  Some aspects I have to admit I don't fully understand. For example, if I make the array `d` ints, as the values are only ever +-1, the code runs about 10% more slowly so I have left it as float64s.

> Is there anything else I can do to speed up the code?

---

This is the result of cython -a . As you can see everything in the loop is compiled to C so the basic optimizations have worked.

[image: Result of cython -a]

Here is the same function in numpy which is over 100 times slower than my current cython version.

```
def npperm(M):
    n = M.shape[0]
    d = np.ones(n)
    j =  0
    s = 1
    f = np.arange(n)
    v = M.sum(axis=0)
    p = np.prod(v)
    while (j < n-1):
        v -= 2*d[j]*M[j]
        d[j] = -d[j]
        s = -s
        prod = np.prod(v)
        p += s*prod
        f[0] = 0
        f[j] = f[j+1]
        f[j+1] = j+1
        j = f[0]
    return p/2**(n-1)
```

---

**Timings updated**

Here are timings (using ipython) of my cython version, the numpy version and romeric's improvement to the cython code. I have set the seed for reproducibility.

```
from scipy.stats import ortho_group
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import permlib # This loads in the functions from permlib.pyx
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(7)
M = ortho_group.rvs(23) #Creates a random orthogonal matrix 
%timeit permlib.npperm(M) # The numpy version
1 loop, best of 3: 44.5 s per loop
%timeit permlib.permfunc(M) # The cython version
1 loop, best of 3: 273 ms per loop
%timeit permlib.permfunc_modified(M) #romeric's improvement
10 loops, best of 3: 198 ms per loop
M = ortho_group.rvs(28)
%timeit permlib.permfunc(M) # The cython version run on a 28x28 matrix
1 loop, best of 3: 15.8 s per loop
%timeit permlib.permfunc_modified(M) # romeric's improvement run on a 28x28 matrix
1 loop, best of 3: 12.4 s per loop
```

> Can the cython code be sped up at all?

I am using gcc and the CPU is the AMD FX 8350.

Comment: Yes: you could ask this on [codereview.se].

Comment: @RadLexus Thank you.  However, it seems cython questions are rare there. There have been 30 ever!

Comment: @eleanora: it's with that sort of reasoning that that number stays low.

Comment: `@Rad Lexus`, don't recommend Code Review unless you are prepared to answer this topic there.  There aren't enough skilled `numpy` and `cython` programmers hanging around that board to give good and timely answers.  I'm currently one of the most active `numpy` coders there, and my reputation is only 1000.

Comment: I've added `numpy` tag, and take off the `optimization` one.  This is a common numpy/cython question on SO - how to get the best speed improvement from the cython port.

Comment: It might help if you showed the numpy original, and compared the speedup.  It's hard to grasp the overall action from the cythonized code.  Often when people don't get as much speedup as expected, it's because the code is still calling Python or numpy functions a lot.  You get best speed when everything in the inner loops is pure `c`.

Comment: @hpaulj That's a good point. I have included the result of cython -a to show that there are no hugely obvious problems.  It's not that the code is slow currently, it's just that I would like it to be as fast as possible.  Someone suggested typed memoryviews, for example. I don't know enough about them to tell if they might help.  I will add more when I can.

Comment: I don't know muc about those except what's on this page: http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Comment: @eleanora Memoryviews don't make a huge difference to the speed (my experience is they're slightly slower to set up) but they're a bit more flexible than numpy array (can work with other data types too)

Comment: @DavidW OK thanks. Do you think there is any more speed I can squeeze from my code?  Are there perhaps low level coding tricks that one can borrow from C?

Comment: Can you describe what your Python code is actually meant to accomplish? The stuff in the `while`-loop, especially the manipulation of `j`,  is hard to follow.

Comment: @RolandSmith Question updated. Please ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: @eleanora Have you considered actually using numpy in your Python code? This would make it a lot simpler and probably faster. For example, to get column `n` from a matrix you could just write `M[:,n]`. Calculating `v` would simply become `M.sum(0)`.

Comment: @RolandSmith It was much slower using just numpy when I tried.  Do you have a clever way of doing for i in xrange(n):
        v[i] -= 2*d[j]*M[j][i] ?  I will add some test code later so we can time these options.

Comment: @eleanora Assuming you're multiplying a column of `M` by a number (`2*d[j]`). Try `v = 2*d[j]*M[:,j]`.

Comment: @RolandSmith I added the numpy version and the timings. I suspect any speed up will come from low level C codings tricks (and/or SSE magic).

Comment: In addition to everything else, try adding the compiler directive ```@cython.cdivision(True)``` to avoid that your code checks zero division.

Comment: @sebacastroh Thank you. I will try that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on the code of @romeric posted before. I corrected the code and simplified it, and added the `cdivision`compiler directive.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False) 
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
def permfunc_modified_2(np.ndarray [double, ndim =2, mode='c'] M):
    cdef:
        int n = M.shape[0], s=1, i, j
        int *f = <int*>malloc(n*sizeof(int))
        double *d = <double*>malloc(n*sizeof(double))
        double *v = <double*>malloc(n*sizeof(double))
        double p = 1, prod

    for i in range(n):
        v[i] = 0.
        for j in range(n):
            v[i] += M[j,i]
        p *= v[i]
        f[i] = i
        d[i] = 1
    j = 0
    while (j < n-1):
        prod = 1.
        for i in range(n):
            v[i] -= 2.*d[j]*M[j, i]
            prod *= v[i]
        d[j] = -d[j]
        s = -s            
        p += s*prod
        f[0] = 0
        f[j] = f[j+1]
        f[j+1] = j+1
        j = f[0]

    free(d)
    free(f)
    free(v)
    return p/pow(2.,(n-1))
```

The original code of @romeric didn't initialize `v`, so you get different results sometimes. Additionally, I combined the two loops before the `while` and the two loops inside of the `while` respectively.

Finally, the comparison

```
In [1]: from scipy.stats import ortho_group
In [2]: import permlib
In [3]: import numpy as np; np.random.seed(7)
In [4]: M = ortho_group.rvs(5)
In [5]: np.equal(permlib.permfunc(M), permlib.permfunc_modified_2(M))
Out[5]: True
In [6]: %timeit permfunc(M)
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.5 µs per loop
In [7]: %timeit permlib.permfunc_modified_2(M)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 µs per loop
In [8]: M = ortho_group.rvs(15)
In [9]: np.equal(permlib.permfunc(M), permlib.permfunc_modified_2(M))
Out[9]: True
In [10]: %timeit permlib.permfunc(M)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop
In [11]: %timeit permlib.permfunc_modified_2(M)
1000 loops, best of 3: 432 µs per loop
In [12]: M = ortho_group.rvs(28)
In [13]: np.equal(permlib.permfunc(M), permlib.permfunc_modified_2(M))
Out[13]: True
In [14]: %timeit permlib.permfunc(M)
1 loop, best of 3: 14 s per loop
In [15]: %timeit permlib.permfunc_modified_2(M)
1 loop, best of 3: 5.73 s per loop
```

Comment: Brilliant! I couldn't work out why the code sometimes gave the wrong answer.  Thank you.  I think the multiplication by 2 can be moved out of the loop, right?

Comment: Yes, you can write ```d[i] = 2.``` and ```v[i] -= d[j]*M[j,i]```, but that won't change the perfomance of the code

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much you can do with your `cython` function, as it is already well optimised. However, you will still be able to get a moderate speed-up by completely avoiding the calls to `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.math cimport pow

cdef inline double sum_axis(double *v, double *M, int n):
    cdef:
        int i, j
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            v[i] += M[j*n+i]


@cython.boundscheck(False) 
@cython.wraparound(False)
def permfunc_modified(np.ndarray [double, ndim =2, mode='c'] M):
    cdef:
        int n = M.shape[0], j=0, s=1, i
        int *f = <int*>malloc(n*sizeof(int))
        double *d = <double*>malloc(n*sizeof(double))
        double *v = <double*>malloc(n*sizeof(double))
        double p = 1, prod

    sum_axis(v,&M[0,0],n)

    for i in range(n):
        p *= v[i]
        f[i] = i
        d[i] = 1

    while (j < n-1):
        for i in range(n):
            v[i] -= 2.*d[j]*M[j, i]
        d[j] = -d[j]
        s = -s
        prod = 1
        for i in range(n):
            prod *= v[i]
        p += s*prod
        f[0] = 0
        f[j] = f[j+1]
        f[j+1] = j+1
        j = f[0]

    free(d)
    free(f)
    free(v)
    return p/pow(2.,(n-1))
```

Here are essential checks and timings:

```
In [1]: n = 12
In [2]: M = np.random.rand(n,n)
In [3]: np.allclose(permfunc_modified(M),permfunc(M))
True
In [4]: n = 28
In [5]: M = np.random.rand(n,n)
In [6]: %timeit permfunc(M) # your version
1 loop, best of 3: 28.9 s per loop
In [7]: %timeit permfunc_modified(M) # modified version posted above
1 loop, best of 3: 21.4 s per loop
```

**EDIT**
Lets perform some basic `SSE` vectorisation by unrolling the inner `prod` loop, that is change the loop in the above code to the following

```
# define t1, t2 and t3 earlier as doubles
t1,t2,t3=1.,1.,1.
for i in range(0,n-1,2):
    t1 *= v[i]
    t2 *= v[i+1]
# define k earlier as int
for k in range(i+2,n):
    t3 *= v[k]
p += s*(t1*t2*t3)
```

and now the timing

```
In [8]: %timeit permfunc_modified_vec(M) # vectorised
1 loop, best of 3: 14.0 s per loop
```

So almost **2X** speed-up over the original optimised cython code, not bad.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Two questions. a) Could it help if I used single precision floats rather than doubles and b) Is there any way to help the compiler vectorize the code?

Comment: A change of double to single might or might not help depending on the architecture and compiler. Regarding vectorisation, check my updated answer

Comment: @eleanora Oh. When unrolling you have to make sure that the for loop size is a multiple of step size (2 in this case). I have updated the answer now. Also your code has overflow problem for varaible `p` as it blows up very soon. As a result the `SSE` and scalar codes would lead to different results for larger `M`.

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: I'm the core dev of the tool mentioned below.*

As an alternative to Cython, you can give [Pythran](http://pythran.readthedocs.io) a try.
A single annotation to the original NumPy code:

```
#pythran export npperm(float[:, :])
import numpy as np
def npperm(M):
    n = M.shape[0]
    d = np.ones(n)
    j =  0
    s = 1
    f = np.arange(n)
    v = M.sum(axis=0)
    p = np.prod(v)
    while j < n-1:
        v -= 2*d[j]*M[j]
        d[j] = -d[j]
        s = -s
        prod = np.prod(v)
        p += s*prod
        f[0] = 0
        f[j] = f[j+1]
        f[j+1] = j+1
        j = f[0]
    return p/2**(n-1)
```

compiled with:

```
> pythran perm.py
```

yields a speedup similar to the one with Cython:

```
> # numpy version
> python -mtimeit -r3 -n1 -s 'from scipy.stats import ortho_group; from perm import npperm; import numpy as np; np.random.seed(7); M = ortho_group.rvs(23)' 'npperm(M)'
1 loops, best of 3: 21.7 sec per loop
> # pythran version
> pythran perm.py
> python -mtimeit -r3 -n1 -s 'from scipy.stats import ortho_group; from perm import npperm; import numpy as np; np.random.seed(7); M = ortho_group.rvs(23)' 'npperm(M)' 
1 loops, best of 3: 171 msec per loop
```

with no need to reimplement `sum_axis` (Pythran takes care of that).

More interesting, Pythran is capable of recognizing several vectorizable (in the sense of generating SSE/AVX intrinsics) patterns, through an option flag:

```
> pythran perm.py -DUSE_BOOST_SIMD -march=native
>  python -mtimeit -r3 -n10 -s 'from scipy.stats import ortho_group; from perm import npperm; import numpy as np; np.random.seed(7); M = ortho_group.rvs(23)' 'npperm(M)' 
10 loops, best of 3: 93.2 msec per loop
```

which makes a final x232 speedup with respect to the NumPy version, a speedup comparable to the unrolled Cython version, without much manual tuning.

Comment: This is very interesting thank you! I will test your code properly in a few days and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one obvious optimization is to set d[i] to -2 and +2 and avoid the multiplication by 2. I suspect this won't make any difference, but still.

Another is to make sure the C++ compiler that compiles the resulting code has all the optimizations turned on (especially vectorization).

The loop that calculates the new v[i]s can be parallelized with [Cython's support of OpenMP](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html). At 30 iterations this also might not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. You are right about the factor of 2.  The cython code is C (not C++). I will try playing with the compiler flags and see if it makes any difference.  I think I would need to parallelize the main while loop as you suggest which would be doable if I used a different way to compute the Gray codes.